# How do i add scripts and stylesheets inside yii module

Tags: php, yii

i am new to yii. 
I just created a module in yii
 the file structure is as follows

```
 -yii
  -protected
     -modules
        -admin
           -controller
           -model
           -view
               -layout
                    -main.php
           -css
               -style.css
           -images
               -logo.jpg
```

i was able to set the layout to like this

```
'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

           'admin'=>array(
                 'layoutPath' => 'protected/modules/admin/views/layouts',  ;
```

)

and now the layout is rendered from the admin module the problem is that i cant load the stylesheets using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/protected/modules/admin/css/reset.css"  media="all">
```

Does anybody knows the correct way to load stylesheets in yii

Comment: If your config file, add one parameter as an array and store the path of module to it. Use the relative path in your href while specifying path for image and css. This is one way. The other is ofcourse having all the files in your base path. i.e. /css /images in your root directory.

Comment: @UjjwalPrajapati yes just for the sake of getting it right i would do something like that... but i know this is not the right method..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everything under your protected folder its indeed, protected, and not public accessible.

in your case, that you are using a module and your files are inside protected folders, your need to 'publish' them to be public accessible. the default public folder for published stuff in Yii its called 'assets'. and to publish we will be using [CAssetManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager).

First create a folder that contains all your css, js and images that you'd need public access to. name it whatever you want, but the standard its 'assets', so taht your file structure looks like this:

```
 -yii
  -protected
     -modules
        -admin
           -controller
           -model
           -view
               -layout
                    -main.php
           -assets
               -css
                   -style.css
               -js
               -images
                   -logo.jpg
```

In your module create a property that will store the public url of the published asset, and a method to access it.

```
private $_assetsUrl;

public function getAssetsUrl()
{
    if ($this->_assetsUrl === null)
        $this->_assetsUrl = Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(
            Yii::getPathOfAlias('admin.assets') );
    return $this->_assetsUrl;
}
```

You can then access your assets like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
         type="text/css"
         href="<?php echo $this->module->assetsUrl; ?>/css/main.css"/>
   ...
   <div id="logo">
   <?php echo CHtml::link(
                 CHtml::image($this->module->assetsUrl.'/images/logo.png'),
                 array('/xxii')); ?>
   </div>
```

[Further reading](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/)