# Yii include CSS and javascript file

Tags: yii, module

I have create  a `admin` module in the `yii` and I want the module use the customized layout.
so I placed the *css* and *js* file in `protected/module/admin/assets`,how can I include the *css* and *js* file in this folder?

and now I have another problem:
I have put the file in the `protected/modules/admin/css/assetsbootstrap.min.css` folder,and I can not include it anyway,even I use the absolute path.I also try it in the other way like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/protected/modules/admin/css/assetsbootstrap.min.css" />
```

is this way does not work in the module?

Comment: still thank you Telvin Nguyen!I got it!

Comment: I sloved myq question by read this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969358/how-do-i-add-scripts-and-stylesheets-inside-yii-module

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include CSS,javascript file in Yii Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998449/include-css-javascript-file-in-yii-framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this extension out

[Yii admin module](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-dashboard/)

Open AdminModule.php, there is location where used for configuration your admin module. I just post the parts what you need

```
public function getAssetsUrl()
    {
        if (!isset($this->assetsUrl))
        {
            $assetsPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('admin.assets');
            $this->assetsUrl = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish($assetsPath, false, -1, $this->forceCopyAssets);
        }

        return $this->assetsUrl;
    }


protected function registerCoreCss()
    {
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($this->getAssetsUrl() . '/css/admin.css');
    }

protected function registerScript(){
    $js_arr = array('jquery.min.js', 'jqueryui.js'); //put what js file name that you need to import from admin assets folder
    foreach($js_arr as $filename){
        Yii::app()->getClientScript()->->registerScriptFile($this->getAssetsUrl().'/js/'.$filename, CClientScript::POS_END);
    }
}
```

And then in `init()`

```
public function init(){
    //set import ...
    // configure module ...
    // configure component  ....

    $this->registerCoreCss();
    $this->registerScript();

}
```

Comment: I think this way is a little complexed,is there some other way?In my opinion,i want to define a constant in the 'main' config file located in the config folder,but it does not work!

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/yourscript.js');
$cs->registerCssFile($baseUrl.'/css/yourcss.css');
```

OR

by editing config/main.php

```
// application components
  'components'=>array(
         // ...
        'clientScript'=>array(
            'packages'=>array(
                'jquery'=>array(
                    'baseUrl'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/',
                    'js'=>array('jquery.min.js'),
                )
            ),
        ),
        // ...
  ),
```

See more: [Yii include Javascript, css file](http://www.codexamples.com/98/how-to-include-javascript-css-in-yii/)